# unable to do play/pause in soundcloud

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

We want to retain the status of iframe in any track clicked in list. But
    we are unable to call the play/pause event twice. Play/pause event getting called on the first time when READY event fires.

we are embeding the iframe urlend using flag which we reset on play/pause event of iframe with id="soundcloud_widget" as mentioned below in javascript code.

> Html:

```
<div class="player-container">
 <div class="player-top">
    <iframe id="soundcloud_widget"  name="someFrame" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/420638724%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-g3rwu&amp;color=e13a7b&amp;auto_play=true&amp;show_user=false&amp;download=false&amp;show_artwork=false" width="420" height="120" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
 </div>              
  <div class="song-header">
      <div class="col-xs-9">Track</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 tac pl">Duration</div>
  </div>
  <div class="songs-container" id="musicli">                          
    <div class="songs">
       <div class="col-xs-9">
       <a class ="mp3list"  href="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/420638724%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-g3rwu&amp;color=e13a7b"        target="soundcloud_widget">Jagat Kalyani Bhavana</a></div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 tac">2:30</div>
       </div>
    <div class="songs">
      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <a class ="mp3list" href="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/420638696%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-dZniI&amp;color=e13a7b"          target="soundcloud_widget">Dada Bhagwan na Asim Jay Jay Kar Ho</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 tac">3:30</div>
    </div>

  </div>                                             

</div>
```

> Javascript:

```
  var iframeid = "soundcloud_widget";
  LoadWidget();
    $("a").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(plyflg);
       if(plyflg==false){

   urlend='&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;download=false&amp;
   show_artwork=false';
           }
         else{

  urlend='&amp;auto_play=true&amp;show_user=false&amp;download=false&amp;
  show_artwork=false';

             }

        var url=$(this).attr("href")+urlend;
        $("#soundcloud_widget").attr("src", url);
    })

  function LoadWidget() {

    var widget1 = SC.Widget(document.getElementById(iframeid));
    widget1.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function (e) {

    });

    widget1.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function (e) {

        plyflg=true;
        console.log('play'+ plyflg);
    });

    widget1.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PAUSE, function (e) {

        plyflg=false;
         console.log('PAUSE'+ plyflg);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the `allow="autoplay"` attribute to your `iframe` in order not to have the following message when calling `play()`.

[image: Uncaught DOMException: The user aborted a request, soundcloud, play]